# Use of the IN condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I can easily create a stored procedure in SQL Server with parameters that I use with `=`, `LIKE` and most operators. But when it comes to using `IN`, I don't really understand what to do, and I can't find a good site to teach me.

Example

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE TEST 
    @Ids --- What type should go here?
    AS BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID IN ( @Ids )
    END
```

Is this possible and if so how ?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: For this project, 2005, but I also use 2008 and 2008R2 sometime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With SQL Server 2008 and above, you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx).

You declare a table type and can use that as a parameter (read only) for stored procedures that can be used in `IN` clauses.

For the different options, I suggest reading the relevant article for your version of the excellent [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html), by Erland Sommarskog.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, there aren't really any other ways than using nvarchar in SQL2005. I was trying to avoid this, but I guess I'll have to live with it.

Comment: @David - XML is another option. The article linked is exhaustive - it will show you all the possible ways to do this with analysis.

Comment: Well, my main fear by using that is that I could eventually create a query so big it would not fit in the varcahr size. But I modified my query a little in a way I believe this will not happen

Comment: @David - That's why I say using XML is one option (XML parameter etc).

Answer (score 1):

I've done this in the past using a Split function that I add to my schema functions as described [here](http://blog.logiclabz.com/sql-server/split-function-in-sql-server-to-break-comma-separated-strings-into-table.aspx)

Then you can do the following:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST 
@Ids --- What type should go here?
AS BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM TableA WHERE ID IN ( dbo.Split(@Ids, ',') )
END
```

Just remember that the IN function always expects a table of values as a result. SQL Server is smart enough to convert strings to this table format, so long as they are specifically written in the procedure.

Another option in your specific example though, could be to use a join. This will have a performance improvement, but often does not really meet a real-world example you need. The join version would be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableA AS ta 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Split(@Ids, ',') AS ids 
        ON ta.Id = ids.items
```

Answer (score 0):

If your asking what I think your asking, I do this every day..

```
WITH myData(FileNames)
AS
(
    SELECT '0608751970%'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1000098846%'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1000101277%'
    UNION ALL SELECT '1000108488%'
)
SELECT DISTINCT f.* 
FROM tblFiles (nolock) f
INNER JOIN myData md 
    ON b.FileNames LIKE md.FileNames
```

Or if your doing this based on another table:

```
WITH myData(FileNames)
AS
(
    SELECT RTRIM(FileNames) + '%'
    FROM tblOldFiles
    WHERE Active=1
)
SELECT DISTINCT f.* 
FROM tblFiles (nolock) f
INNER JOIN myData md 
    ON b.FileNames LIKE md.FileNames
```